# Elixir @spec annotation for atoms

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

The function below is written in Elixir:

```
def count(:comments, id), do 0
```

When I want to get its documentation using 'h' in iex, this is printed out:

```
iex> h Module.count

def count(atom, id)
```

But I want ':comments' to appear on the documentation using 'h'.

```
iex> h Module.count

def count(:comments, id)
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to declare the function with a bodyless clause. See the Elixir docs on [documenting function arguments](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/writing-documentation.html#function-arguments), or [the Writing Documentation doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/writing-documentation.html) as a whole.

EDIT:

Looking at it further, while it's not exactly what you're looking for adding

```
@doc"""
  count(:comments, id)
"""
```

before your function definition will get you closer to what you're looking for.